# Javascript if statement only works in Console or Refresh IE11

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of code that gets the server time(set by PHP) for example 12:00 and compares it to one in an array. This works in Chrome & Firefox, for some reason it only works in IE11 when the developer tools is open or if you refresh it when the times match.

```
function checktime(){

    var triggerPopup;
    var trigger_time = "";
    var server_time = "";
    $.get("server_time.php", function(data, status){
        var chktime;
        for(i = 0; i < popover_arr.length; i++) {
            trigger_time = popover_arr[i].trigger_time;
            server_time = data;
            triggerPopup = false;
            if(server_time == trigger_time){
                triggerPopup = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(triggerPopup==true){
            showPopup(i)
        }else{
            chktime = setTimeout(function(){checktime()},1000);
        }

    });

}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `only works in IE11 when the developer tools`,  not sure if this is still the case, but I remember when using IE in the past if dev tools is not open, there is no console, so `console.log()` etc would error.

Comment: earlier versions of IE don't support console.log()